# Moments of the prime counting function given the moments of the second Chebyshev function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, probability-distributions

I have read this article (Montgomery and Soundararajan: Primes in short intervals. http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0409258 ). In the second page of the article, it is stated that the mean and variance of $\psi(n+h)-\psi(n)$, in a given range of h and n, tends to $h$ and $h \log\frac{h}{n}$ respectively, being $\psi(n)$ the second Chebyshev function. On the other hand, I have read this question ([Are the primes normally distributed? Or is this the Riemann hypothesis?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/163274/are-the-primes-normally-distributed-or-is-this-the-riemann-hypothesis)) in which it is stated that the mean and variance of $\pi(n+h)-\pi(n)$ tends to $\frac{h}{\log n}$ and $\frac{h}{(\log n)^{2}} \log\frac{h}{n}$ in that range. My question is, ¿ How can I obtain the moments of the prime counting function from the moments of the second Chebyshev function. ?

Comment: Should be $\log n/h$ throughout.  In a short interval $[n,n+h]$ the weighting by $\Lambda$ is just weighting by approximately $\log n$; don't worry about prime powers since there are so few of those.